# Is my U.S. driver's license valid in Europe?

Tags: europe, legal, driving-licenses, czech-republic

Can I drive using my U.S. (New York State) license in the European Union (if the answer depends on the country, please answer for Czech Republic)?

Comment: Keep in mind that any regulations form the U.S. side are likely state-wise: I.e. You can transfer your NJ driver license to a German driver license but your NY driver license is not eligible for a transfer to a German driver license. But for just visiting and driving around, the IDP should be fine within the EU.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could simply get an [International Driving Permit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Driving_Permit). This, coupled with your US driver's license, is recognised in over 70 countries.

The American Automobile Association and the American Automobile Touring Alliance's [National Automobile Club](http://www.nationalautoclub.com) are the only entities in the United States to issue IDPs.

As for recognising your country license, each EU country is different. No EU country is obliged to recognise an international license, even if already recognised by a fellow country.

[From the State Department](http://travel.state.gov/content/passports/english/country/czech-republic.html):

> An International Driving Permit (IDP), available from AAA (in the United States only), must accompany a U.S. driver’s license; failure to have the IDP with a valid license may result in denial of an insurance claim after an accident.

So since you need an IDP for the Czech Republic, I'd recommend just getting it and then you're covered for any European country.

Comment: I did this last week and it took literally 10 minutes, walk-in (no appointment) at the AAA. They take the passport-sized photos you need right there, too.

Answer (score 2):

Here's information about driver's license Latvia: http://www-en.csdd.lv/?lngID=EN&pageID=1181212466
Basically it means you can use your US license for up to one year. After that you neet to get Latvian driver's license by passing driving test.